# Unknown PerlIO layer class ':utf8 :std'

Tags: perl, utf-8

[Doc](https://perldoc.pl/open.html) states that expressions are equivalent:

```
use open ':locale';
use open IO => ':locale';
```

But why next are not?

```
use open ':utf8 :std';       # Unknown PerlIO layer class ':utf8 :std' (need IN, OUT or IO) at ...
use open IO => ':utf8 :std'; # No error happened
```

Comment: Both will fail on 5.18 and 5.26, though slightly differently. How old is this Perl?

Comment: @Schwern: 5.24.1

Comment: @brian-d-foy: This question is not duplicate. This is about how to combine layers. That question you have linked is about which layers I should use. Both use similar expressions so questions are related, but actually are not duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank @Grinnz on IRC:

Because `:std is not a layer, it must be its own argument in the list`

So code should be:

```
use open ':utf8', ':std';
```